# Validate VML in HTML emails using C#

Tags: c#, html-email, vml

I'm looking for a C# library or Web Service that will parse an HTML email that contains VML and report any syntax errors.

Does anyone know if such a beast exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a library or web service - although that could well just be due to a lack of knowledge on my part - but you could probably write your own validator reasonably easily. There are published schemas for the various versions of Word HTML emails and Office (e.g. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0B764C08-0F86-431E-8BD5-EF0E9CE26A3A&displaylang=en, http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=101) so you should be able to use them to validate your content?